# What is the best practice to set the Theme of my CustomDialog that extends Dialog implements OnClickListener

Tags: android, background, dialog, themes

I am currently having a big issue in my application.
I use the Theme.Light in my whole application. The result is great, but I noticed that in ICS, the Dialog have white background, and in previous versions, the background was black (see screenshot below)

My first idea was to use different layout for the items and use layout-v14 with dark text and layout folder with white text.

That will be working but I really would like to set the theme of the Dialog like I do with classic dialog:

```
return new AlertDialog.Builder(AlertDialogSamples.this, AlertDialog.THEME_TRADITIONAL)
.create();
```

The problem is now that my custom Dialog extends Dialog and I have no more the possibility to play with the builder:

```
public class MyCustomDialog extends Dialog implements OnClickListener {

    int THEME=AlertDialog.THEME_TRADITIONAL;

    public MyCustomDialog(Activity plannerActivity) {
        super(plannerActivity);
        View myView=//Something;
        setContentView(myView);
    }
}
```

and in my main code:

```
new MyCustomDialog(getActivity()).show();
```

As I have no more access to the builder, I cannot change the Theme of my CustomDialog and I am completely stuck in my app.

Thank a lot for any help!

[image]

**EDIT TO ADD MORE INFO**

As advised by Vineet Shukla, I tried new DialogYour(Activity.this, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar), but  the constructor DialogYour(Activity, int) is undefined.

I cannot override the DialogYour with a theme, as some stuff are internal to android!

When I look into the Dialog Code:

```
Dialog(Context context, int theme, boolean createContextWrapper) {
    if (theme == 0) {
        TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
        context.getTheme().resolveAttribute(com.android.internal.R.attr.dialogTheme,
                outValue, true);
        theme = outValue.resourceId;
    }

    mContext = createContextWrapper ? new ContextThemeWrapper(context, theme) : context;
    mWindowManager = (WindowManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Window w = PolicyManager.makeNewWindow(mContext);
    mWindow = w;
    w.setCallback(this);
    w.setWindowManager(mWindowManager, null, null);
    w.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    mUiThread = Thread.currentThread();
    mListenersHandler = new ListenersHandler(this);
}
```

I cannot override, because PolicyManager belong to com.android.internal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried `custom dialog` but not this way. I have `overridden` the `onCreateDialog` in the `activity` like this with theme `android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar`

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
Dialog dialog = new DialogYour(Activity.this, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
if(id == YOUR_ID){
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.layout);
    //initialize your views here ...
}

return dialog;  
}
```

You can try this way and you will achieve your desired layout for custom layout.

**Note:** You can also try with the theme `android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar` in your code.

**Edit1:**

I have not tried but To set the theme in your case you can try like this:

```
ConnectionDialog dialog = new ConnectionDialog(getActivity()); 
dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar;
dialog.show();
```

**Edit2:** I have tested your code and the issue was in your `constructor`.

```
public class MyCustomDialog extends Dialog implements OnClickListener {

    int THEME=AlertDialog.THEME_TRADITIONAL;

    public MyCustomDialog(Context context, int theme) {
        super(context, theme);
        View myView=//Something;
        setContentView(myView);
    }
}
```

now call the above dialog like this:

```
 MyCustomDialog dialog = new MyCustomDialog (this, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
    dialog.show();
```

Comment: The problem is that the constructor DialogYour(Activity, int) is undefined! How did you defined the DialogYour in your example?

Comment: thru this line: Dialog dialog = new DialogYour(Activity.this, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);

Comment: Yes, but DialogYour(Activity, int) is undefined! your line cannot work. Wait 2 minuts, will add code in the first post, and as I have to set a lot of click listeners, I cannot use default dialog, I Need to create a new class:  MyCustomDialog extends Dialog

Comment: Does not work, but we are for sure close to something, I guess. I am busy trying to change everything possible, but without success.

Comment: Please see the edit2 section in the answer and I have found the issue in your code..

Comment: Answer accepted! Thank a lot! If you still have a few minutes to waste, I have now issues to set the title!

Comment: your dialog layout tells that title is the part of your layout..instantiate your view and set the title there...